# jenkins is not running my python script from pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `.jenkinsfile` that is in charge of my CI. This is the relevant snippet (from Jenkins "replay"):

```
try {
    sh("pytest...")
} catch (e) {
    sh("./clean_script.sh || true")
    throw e
} finally ...
```

When looking at the console output, I can detect (upon failure) this section: *`[STAGE_NAME] + ./clean_script.sh`*, meaning I got to the `catch` part.

However, the following lines, which I added in a later commit and rerun, are not executed. My addition looks like:

```
try {
    sh("pytest...")
} catch (e) {
    sh("./clean_script.sh || true")
    println "start"
    def good = ${GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT}
    sh("python my_py.py ${good}")
    println "end"
    throw e
}  finally ...
```

I don't see even the "start" line, which I don't understand (the "finally" part is executed and printed)... Suppose the py script fails, or the `good` isn't assigned correctly, why shuold it affect the first `println`?

Comment: maybe `sh("pytest...")` passed or `sh("./clean_script.sh || true")` failed

Comment: @minas The `|| true` probably guarantees it does not fail.

Comment: "Suppose the py script fails, or the good isn't assigned correctly, why shuold it affect the first println" Likely because the `stdout` buffer is not flushed at that point. I have seen this behavior before in Jenkins Pipeline, and it affects a lot of languages really.